# mongodb couldnot start service status 100 windows 8.1 32bit

Tags: mongodb, windows-8.1

I have installed MongoDB community server 3.2.19 32 bit signed version in my tablet but could not be able to start it. Have done configuration and set path to log as well, created a registry and a service also. But it always return with same error code 100.

Comment: You really should be scrolling down the available answers and reading up on `--dbpath`. But that's also in the documentation, which you should also be reading.

Comment: I hv set path as C:\data \db &log path C:\data\log but still getting the same error

Comment: That's not what your question says. In fact your question does not actually show what you have done at all. You need show your steps "within your question". But really, I don't think you even really looked at the "many" existing answers to this or even [followed the install instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/). There are plenty of **very specific** guides out there. Read them.